# Unzipping a zip-file with zlib returns error permanently in IOS

Tags: objective-c, zlib

I work with with iOS and I want to decompress a .zip file to memory using zlib, but it always returns error with the code `-3`.

My code is below:

```
NSData *sData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mactxt" ofType:@"zip"]];
NSData *srcData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mactxt" ofType:@"rtf"]];
unsigned int l = srcData.length;
unsigned long srcLen = sData.length;

unsigned long dstLen = l;
void * dest =malloc(dstLen);
memset(dest, 0x00, dstLen);
const void * src =[sData bytes];
int a = uncompress(dest, &dstLen, src, srcLen);
if (a==0) {
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:dest length:dstLen];
    [data writeToFile:[self dataFilePath:@"matxt.rtf"] atomically:YES];
}
```

How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

It is failing because it's the wrong format. `.zip` archives are not compressed with zlib -- they're using PKZIP, which is a somewhat complex archive format that often contains multiple files, not just a single data stream.